# Ruby: undefined method `include?' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby

I can't find the proper fix for my delete conditional expression error, specifically 'include?'

```
when "delete"
  puts "Please type verbatim task to delete:"
  target_task = gets.chomp
  if @all_tasks.include?("target_task")
    @all_tasks.delete("target_task")
    puts "#{target_task} was removed from list"
  end
```

Full code [linked here](https://gist.github.com/zahzee/6f8c1b7b297d5a3e3cff) at GitHub. Line 70.

I've tried the proper include? format linked [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-include-3F), tried every combination of parenthesis and quotations for `target_task`, and tried including `my_list.@all_tasks.include?` too. No dice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `@all_tasks` is an instance variable of the `List` class and you try to access it outside the class. To do that, add

```
attr_reader :all_tasks
```

inside the definition of the `List` class and call

```
if my_list.all_tasks.include?("target_task")
```

instead.